# Alternative command of gunicorn for waitress

Tags: django, gunicorn, waitress

So basically I'm trying to use gunicorn on Windows using the command

```
gunicorn core.wsgi:application -w 4
```

I know that gunicorn does not work on Windows bc the package 'fcntl' does not exist in Windows. The alternative to gunicorn on Windows is waitress, is there a waitress command that can achieve the same result as the gunicorn command above? Thank you in advance.